# If P(X>Y)=m and P(X>k)=m then E(Y) =k

Tags: probability, expectation

I feel like the statement would only be true if the median of Y was equal to the mean of Y ie Y is symmetrical.  Because the probability only cares about the median and expected value cares only median.  That is, i believe If P(X>Y)=m and P(X>k)=m then median(Y) =k is definitely true but the title is only true when median=mean iff distribution of Y is symmetrical.

Comment: More information about random variables $X,Y$ is needed to make such a conclusion.  For example, let $X$ be a discrete random variable that takes $1/3$ and $2/3$ with equal probability, and let $Y$ be a continuous random variable which is uniformly distributed on $[0,1]$ and independent of $X$.  Then $P(X\gt Y) = 1/2$ and $P(X\gt 0.52) = 1/2$, but $E(Y) \neq 0.52$.  The point is $k$ might be varied without changing the truth of the premises, but if $Y$ has an expected value, it can only have one.

Comment: And if I add the premise that X and Y must be continuous?

Comment: I'm getting tired, but I'm thinking one can take $m=0$ and choose $k$ in various ways (with $Y$ always greater than $X$) that gives a similar counterexample (multiple values for $k$ but $E(Y)$ well determined).

Comment: You need a ton more conditions.  E.g. even a continuous $X$ can be "bimodal" and approximate the discrete $X$ proposed by @hardmath arbitrarily closely, esp. if the pdf of $X$ has value $0$ for a section in the middle.